# Power of an equation number

Tags: equations, numbering

Suppose I want the output in latex to be some equation number, for example `(1.1)`. Then we use the command

```
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
```

Now I want the output to be `$(1.1)^{p}$` for some `$p$`. That is I want the output to the power of an equation number.

Is there some command for that?

Comment: `$\text{\eqref{<label>}}^p$` (requires package `amsmath`)

Comment: Thank you very much. But I think there is a little misunderstanding. Suppose I use the command \begin{equation}\label{1}\end{equation}, then I get some output with an equation number, for example (1.1) but not with a power. Here I want the output an equation with a power for example (1.1)^p.

Comment: Then look up `\tag{...} `

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: `\label` is unrelated to the printed number it is an internal identifier like id=".." in html, to specify the printed label use `\tag` from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: I just came here to read about the secret powers of equation numbers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If p is a fixed exponent, it can easily be done with the `\newtagform` command  from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %
\newtagform{power}({)$ ^p $}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Fermat’s equation}

\usetagform{power}

\begin{equation}
  x^n + y^n = z^n \label{pdf}
\end{equation}
For $n = 2$, equation \eqref{pdf} is known as the \emph{Pythagorean triples} problem.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\tag*`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We have a standard equation
\begin{equation}
|a+b| \le |a|+|b| \label{standard}
\end{equation}
but also its generalization to different exponents
\begin{equation}
\sqrt[\uproot{2}p]{|a|^p+|b|^p}\le |a|+|b| \tag*{(\ref{standard})\makebox[0pt][l]{$^p$}}
\end{equation}
for every $p\ge1$.

We can refer to equation~\eqref{standard} and to equation~\eqref{standard}$^p$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between `\tag` and `\tag*`?

Comment: @LSpice `\tag` supplies the parentheses around the argument, `\tag*` doesn't. SInce I wanted the exponent outside the parentheses, `\tag*` is necessary.